# kafka error conection with 3 Zookeepers y 3 Brokers Kafka

Tags: docker, apache-kafka

I am installing from https://github.com/conduktor/kafka-stack-docker-compose/blob/master/zk-multiple-kafka-multiple.yml unsuccessfully.

These are my docker conatiners:

```
f158c8d436fb   confluentinc/cp-kafka:7.1.1       "/etc/confluent/dock…"   22 minutes ago   Up 13 minutes   9092/tcp, 0.0.0.0:9093->9093/tcp, :::9093->9093/tcp                       kafka2
9bce7c4ec4d3   confluentinc/cp-kafka:7.1.1       "/etc/confluent/dock…"   22 minutes ago   Up 13 minutes   0.0.0.0:9092->9092/tcp, :::9092->9092/tcp                                 kafka1
b92a723835ea   confluentinc/cp-kafka:7.1.1       "/etc/confluent/dock…"   22 minutes ago   Up 13 minutes   9092/tcp, 0.0.0.0:9094->9094/tcp, :::9094->9094/tcp                       kafka3
0e483aa953a3   confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:7.1.1   "/etc/confluent/dock…"   22 minutes ago   Up 13 minutes   2181/tcp, 2888/tcp, 3888/tcp, 0.0.0.0:2182->2182/tcp, :::2182->2182/tcp   zoo2
2fb1b2b8e799   confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:7.1.1   "/etc/confluent/dock…"   22 minutes ago   Up 13 minutes   2181/tcp, 2888/tcp, 3888/tcp, 0.0.0.0:2183->2183/tcp, :::2183->2183/tcp   zoo3
1ffc65f8120f   confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:7.1.1   "/etc/confluent/dock…"   22 minutes ago   Up 13 minutes   2888/tcp, 0.0.0.0:2181->2181/tcp, :::2181->2181/tcp, 3888/tcp             zoo1
```

when I try to execute some command inside the kafka1 container:
kafka-console-producer --broker-list kafka1:9092 --topic first_topic I am getting:

```
[2022-06-26 03:03:36,048] WARN [Consumer clientId=console-consumer, groupId=console-consumer-81981] Connection to node 2147483644 (/127.0.0.1:9094) could not be established. Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
```

if I use localhost in place of kafka1 I get the same error.

Sometimes I can send the message but when I try to consume it I get the same error.

Sometimes the brokers stop without to show any error in the log container.

Thank you.

Comment: It's `kafka1:19092`. If the brokers crash, that's a separate problem. For example, if it's running out of memory, you don't need an equal number of Zookeepers for brokers. And running multiple brokers on one machine isn't really useful.

Comment: I read about performance problems but not error problems ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44110161/why-single-node-multiple-broker-in-kafka-cluster-not-preferred ). In my logs of brokers and zoos I don't have errors only info and warm. I take your advice but I would like to implement my development environment similar to production.

Comment: Your producer and consumers should work the same if they communicate with one broker or 3. But you'll need to use the correct network addresses

Comment: I am not getting a connection error, in fact I am getting a warm between internal brokers, because my command is addressed to the broker1. When I create the topic it works fine.

Comment: `127.0.0.1:9094) could not be established` is definitely a connection error,but it is logged at the WARN level because the client will attempt to reconnect to other brokers. It's failing because you need to use port 19092 for `kafka1` broker, as I said in the first comment. Have you read the duplicate post yet? Do you [understand how advertised listeners property works in Kafka](https://confluent.io/blog/kafka-listeners-explained/)? It's not fully used for topic creation, only for producers or consumers

Comment: I tried as you said with kafka1:19092 and it works fine when I have only one zoo and broker. If I have the client outside docker what is the right way to send the message ?

Comment: It should also work when you have more than one. Outside of docker is also answered in the duplicate post I linked to. [Based on this line](https://github.com/conduktor/kafka-stack-docker-compose/blob/master/zk-multiple-kafka-multiple.yml#L46), you can use `127.0.0.1:9092` or 9093 & 9094 for the other brokers